# Handle NullPointerException no record found in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android

My `class` extends **RecyclerView.Adapter<...>**

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
     return arrayListPacks == null ? 0 : arrayListPacks.size();
     // return 5;
}
```

To get only *5 records* in an `ArrayList`, I have used:

```
return 5;
```

But, I am getting `NullPointer` exception, when there is no record found.

So, **How could I handle this exception ?**

I would like to show *maximum 5* records if exist(s) else handle **NPE**

Comment: Please post the logcat

Comment: How about if you check `arrayListPacks == null && arrayListPacks.isEmpty()` ?

Comment: have you initialized arraylist before using ? eg. Arraylist arrayListPacks  = new Arraylist ();

Comment: I bet you getItemCount isn't causing the NPE, it is in the bindViewHolder

Comment: i think your code is fine. this part of code will never raise an exception. There may be another parts of your code might raise an `Exception`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like this

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

     return arrayListPacks == null ? 0 : (arrayListPack.size() > 5? 5: arrayListPacks.size());
}
```

so if list > 5 return only 5, otherwise, return the size.

But for nullpointerexception, u need to check the logcat and u will find out where and why it happened. check where you initialize the adapter and give the list.

Answer (score 0):

try this..  :)

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
     return arrayListPacks == null ? Collections.<ClassName> emptyList().size(): arrayListPacks.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ManthanB because a null Arraylist means the collection name arrayListPacks points to an unallocated location null. This is quite different than pointing to a valid allocated location that has nothing in it. So allocate by using ArrayList arrayListPacks=new ArrayList(); now  arrayListPacks will expose methods to add new elements